How to use Eagar Loading(preload) in Lucid ORM using Postgres?
I have two tables: User and User_Role. I want to implement the eager loading concept on both the tables query.
I want to eagar-load the role in user query and tried:
    const user = await User.query().preload('roles')


output

[{"id":1,
"fullName":"user with role",
"email":"adminrole@gmail.com",
"createdAt":"2024-12-03T02:11:15.190+00:00",
"updatedAt":"2024-12-03T02:11:15.190+00:00",
"roles":[]
}]


Expected output:


I want the roles to get populated.

Upon debugging the queries: I noticed the follow query are done:
1. select * from "users"
2. select * from "user_roles" where "user_id" in (2,3)

On user_role Query:
    const userRole = await UserRole.query().preload('user', (query) => query.select('fullName'))

output:
[{"id":1,"userId":"2","role":"moderator","user":null}]

Expected output:

I want the user to get populated?

upon debugging, following queries are done:
1. select * from "user_roles"
2. select "full_name", "id" from "users" where "id" in (2)

Below are the details:
User model:
import { DateTime } from 'luxon'
import hash from '@adonisjs/core/services/hash'
import { compose } from '@adonisjs/core/helpers'
import { BaseModel, column, hasMany } from '@adonisjs/lucid/orm'
import { withAuthFinder } from '@adonisjs/auth/mixins/lucid'
import UserRole from './user_role.js'
import type { HasMany } from '@adonisjs/lucid/types/relations'

const AuthFinder = withAuthFinder(() => hash.use('scrypt'), {
  uids: ['email'],
  passwordColumnName: 'password',
})

export default class User extends compose(BaseModel, AuthFinder) {
  @column({ isPrimary: true })
  declare id: number

  @column()
  declare fullName: string | null

  @column()
  declare email: string

  @hasMany(() => UserRole, {
    foreignKey: 'userId',
    localKey: 'id',
  })
  declare roles: HasMany<typeof UserRole>

  @column({ serializeAs: null })
  declare password: string

  @column.dateTime({ autoCreate: true })
  declare createdAt: DateTime

  @column.dateTime({ autoCreate: true, autoUpdate: true })
  declare updatedAt: DateTime | null
}

User table Migration:
import { BaseSchema } from '@adonisjs/lucid/schema'

export default class extends BaseSchema {
  protected tableName = 'users'

  async up() {
    this.schema.createTable(this.tableName, (table) => {
      table.increments('id').notNullable()
      table.string('full_name').nullable()
      table.string('email', 254).notNullable().unique()
      table.string('password').notNullable()
      table.timestamp('created_at').notNullable()
      table.timestamp('updated_at').nullable()
    })
  }

  async down() {
    this.schema.dropTable(this.tableName)
  }
}

User_Role Model:
import { BaseModel, belongsTo, column } from '@adonisjs/lucid/orm'
import type { BelongsTo } from '@adonisjs/lucid/types/relations'
import User from './user.js'

export enum Role {
  Admin = 'admin',
  moderator = 'moderator',
}

export default class UserRole extends BaseModel {
  @column({ isPrimary: true })
  declare id: number

  @column()
  declare userId: number

  @column()
  declare role: Role

  @belongsTo(() => User)
  declare user: BelongsTo<typeof User>
}

User_role_migration:
import { Role } from '#models/user_role'
import { BaseSchema } from '@adonisjs/lucid/schema'

export default class extends BaseSchema {
  protected tableName = 'user_roles'

  async up() {
    this.schema.createTable(this.tableName, (table) => {
      table.increments('id').primary().notNullable()
      table.bigint('user_id').unsigned().notNullable()
      table.foreign('user_id').references('users.id').onDelete('CASCADE')
      table.enum('role', [Role.Admin, Role.GrievanceModerator])
    })
  }

  async down() {
    this.schema.dropTable(this.tableName)
  }
}


